# Rails: How do I create an item in model/controller A from a view in model/controller B?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on my first app in Ruby on Rails and I'm stuck attempting to add a link on the "show" view of one of my models that clones some of the object's own attributes to create a new object in a different model.

For instance, let's say you wanted to let users create their own personal stock portfolio entries from a list of available stocks, passing over current stock price and ticker symbol.

Model A contains the list of available stocks with symbols and prices.

Model B contains the list of personal stocks that belong to each user, also with symbols and prices (cloned from Model A) and a personal description.

I'm trying to allow people to click on a button on the SHOW view for Model A that creates a new instance of Model B, copying the symbol and price from the current A to create a new B.

I tried placing the partial form for personal stocks inside the SHOW view for an available stock, but received this error "First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty."

Any ideas off the bat without having to paste in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have something like `form_for(@personal_stock)` in your partial.  Change it to `form_for(personal_stock)` and then when you render the partial in the list of stocks use:

```
<%= render 'personal_stock/form', :personal_stock => PersonalStock.new(:stock => stock) %>
```

You'll need to also modify the render in your new and edit views for the PersonalStocksController to:

```
<%= render 'form', :personal_stock => @personal_stock %>
```

Comment: Worked great after some tweaking '<%= render 'personal_stock/form', :personal_stock => PersonalStock.new(:stock => stock) %>' to '<%= render 'personal_stock/form', :personal_stock => PersonalStock.new(:symbol => @stock.symbol) %>' Many thanks!